# what is the end point url of my jira tool to update my testcases status using Rest api

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-zephyr

In my jira tool I have installed zephyr plugin to integrate with tests

found some documentation of all the restAPI requests
here https://getzephyr.docs.apiary.io but I am not sure what is the end point url of my jira tool to send these requests

could some one please help me to find

Thanks 
Ketan

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know you have to install the zephyr api in Jira which is a different plugin called "ZAPI". Once you have it, the correct url to make your calls would be something like:
https://yourjiraurl/rest/zapi/...

Comment: Thanks for the info
found this url https://prod-play.zephyr4jiracloud.com in developersection of network section